# How do I show a cubic polynomial does not factorise?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

In particular: $x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x -2 $.

I would know what to do if it had one root which was an integer, however it does not.

any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Eisentein's criterion

Comment: this has one real root at $x = 2.839$ according to my ancient ti-83.

Answer (score 9):

All cubics with real coefficients factorize over the real polynomials. See the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Corollaries) and its corollaries.

Not all cubics with integer coefficients factorize over the integer polynomials. However, if a cubic does factorize this way, one of the factors will be a linear polynomial. That means that there will be a rational root of the polynomial.

Therefore, for a cubic integer polynomial, use the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find any rational roots. If there none, [the cubic does not factor into polynomials with integer coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Factorization).

Comment: There is one more factorization possibility to be considered: when a polynomial (with real coefficients) is factorized over the reals into the product of linear polynomials. This holds iff all roots of a polynomial are real. [A cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has three real roots iff its discrinimant $\Delta=18abcd-4b^3d+b^2c^2-4ac^3-27a^2d^2\ge 0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_nature_of_the_roots). In OP case $\Delta=-44<0$, so the cubic is not factorized over the reals into the product of linear polynomials.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra is a little bit overkill here and not directly helpful; the intermediate-value theorem suffices.